# Macro within macro in C

Tags: c, function, macros

Please help me solving this problem. This is sample code to get line number,file name and var args in C. When I tried to run this, I got some errors. I am sure there are many ways to do this. But I have to use existing code to achieve some functionality. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define MY_MACRO1(fmt, args...)                \
 {                                             \
   char buf_d[1024];                       \
   MY_MACRO2(__FILE__, __LINE__,call_func(buf_d,sizeof(buf_d),fmt,##args));   \
 }   

#define MY_MACRO2(__FILE__, __LINE__,fmt, ...)  printf("%s : %d -> %s : \n",__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__);

char * call_func(char *buf_t, size_t size, const char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap,fmt);
  vsnprintf(buf_t, size, fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return buf_t;
}


int main()
{
  printf("\n Now I am printintg macro....\n");
  MY_MACRO1("Macro is working fine..\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

Please find macro expansion. Last argument in macro (func return value) is missing.

```
char buf_d[1024];
printf("%s : %d -> %s : \n","file.c",35, );;
```

Error:

```
file.c:35:83: error: expected expression
{ char buf_d[1024]; printf("%s : %d -> %s : \n","file.c", 35, );; };
                                                              ^
```

1 error generated.

Comment: Elephant: Why use a macro?

Comment: Why dual-tag this C and C++ when it's neither? You're using a non-standard compiler extension of a compiler you haven't specified in the question. Does it have to become valid C? Does it have to become valid C++? Does it have to become acceptable to your particular compiler? All three would give you different answers. And why on earth choose to redefine `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` as macro parameters?!

Comment: IIRC `fmt ,args...` later followed by a `,##args` is a non-portable extension.  You can use `...` in place of `fmt ,args...`  and `__VA_ARGS__` in place of `fmt,##args`

Comment: @technosaurus Yes for the first part, not necessarily for the second. In `MY_MACRO2`, `fmt` isn't expanded at all, but if it would be extended to expand `fmt`, it's not clear the `fmt` and `args` would still be adjacent.

Comment: Placing a buffer like that in a macro is asking for a whole heap of trouble.  At the very least, surround it with do{}while(0) - but even then, this troubles me.

Comment: So we use a macro to call a macro, that redefines system macros in its parameters and allocates stack memory,  to call a function that uses variadics.  What could go wrong?  I'm running away now.

Comment: At the very least, your macro `#define MY_MACRO2(__FILE__, __LINE__,fmt, ...)  printf("%s : %d -> %s : \n",__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__);` should not be using the pre-defined macros as argument names — at minimum, it invites confusion.  Use `file` and `line`, as in: `#define MY_MACRO2(file, line, fmt, ...)  printf("%s : %d -> %s : \n", file, line, __VA_ARGS__);` — this avoids confusing the preprocessor (and other programmers) as badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `, ...` that means that you MUST supply an argument, which is not your case. You can just modify your macro by naming the argument list and let the preprocessor elude the comma if needed:

```
#define MY_MACRO1(fmt, args...)                \
 {                                             \
   char buf_d[1024];                       \
   MY_MACRO2(__FILE__, __LINE__,call_func(buf_d,sizeof(buf_d),fmt,##args)); \
 }   

#define MY_MACRO2(F,L,fmt,args...)  printf("%s : %d -> %s : \n",F, L, fmt, ##args)
```

Comment: test_macro.c:30:2: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]

I think you are right Jean. But when I tried I got following warning.. It's printing some garbage instead of desired string..test_macro.c:20:69: note: expanded from macro 'DEBUG_APMD_V2'
#define DEBUG_APMD_V2(file, line,fmt, args...)                               printf("%s : %d -> %s : \n",file, line, ##args);
                              ~^
1 warning generated.

Comment: Your example modified like I suggested works for me, may be your real situation is a bit different?

Comment: Note that the notation without the comma before the ellipsis is a GCC (and probably Clang-for-compatibility-with-GCC) extension.

Answer (score 3):

What a mess! Let's clean the things:

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


#define DEBUG_MSG( _msg, ... )  do {print_debug_msg( __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, _msg, ## __VA_ARGS__ ); }while(0)


void print_debug_msg( const char * module, int line, const char * func, const char * fmt, ... )
{
    va_list va;
    char buf[ 1024 ] = {0};

    va_start( va, fmt );
    vsnprintf( buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, va );
    va_end( va );

    printf( "%s:%d - %s() - %s\n", module, line, func, buf );
}


int myfunc( const char * msg )
{
    DEBUG_MSG( "Message: %s",  msg );

    return 0;
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    DEBUG_MSG("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");

    DEBUG_MSG("Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.");

    myfunc( "How vexingly quick daft zebras jump" );

    myfunc("The five boxing wizards jump quickly.");

    return 0;
}

/* eof */
```

Compiling:

```
$ gcc -Wall macro.c -o macro
```

Testing:

```
$ ./macro 
macro.c:32 - main() - The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
macro.c:34 - main() - Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.
macro.c:24 - myfunc() - Message: How vexingly quick daft zebras jump
macro.c:24 - myfunc() - Message: The five boxing wizards jump quickly.
```

References:

> 1) [Recommended C Style and Coding Standards (Macros)](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html#N10488)
>
> 2) [GCC Manual - Standard Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html)

Hope it Helps!